# JavaScript class - Call method when object initialized

Tags: javascript, object

I have a class similar to the one below. How do I call my `init` method when the object is created? I don't want to have to create an instance of my object then call initialize like I do below.

```
var myObj = new myClass(2, true);
myObj.init();

function myClass(v1, v2) 
{
    // public vars
    this.var1 = v1;

    // private vars
    var2 = v2;

    // pub methods
    this.init = function() {
        // do some stuff        
    };

    // private methods
    someMethod = function() {
        // do some private stuff
    };
}
```

Comment: none of the solutions work if properties to be used are actually defined prototype and prototype code happens to be below this constructor function.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

NB. Constructor function names should start with a capital letter to distinguish them from ordinary functions, e.g. `MyClass` instead of `myClass`.

Either you can call `init` from your constructor function:

```
var myObj = new MyClass(2, true);

function MyClass(v1, v2) 
{
    // ...

    // pub methods
    this.init = function() {
        // do some stuff        
    };

    // ...

    this.init(); // <------------ added this
}
```

Or more simply you could just copy the body of the `init` function to the end of the constructor function. No need to actually have an `init` function at all if it's only called once.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried calling 'this.init();' before posting, but I was making the call before the function declaration so that is why it would not work. =]

Comment: How should I do the same if I define my object simply by `var obj = {init: function(){...}}`? How should I call it?

Comment: @Eugene - What's wrong with: `var makeObj = function(x, y) { return { a: x + y }; }` It's a function that creates an object and performs whatever one-time initialization you require before returning it. Sometimes called a factory function.

Comment: Well parentlly nothing wrong with it, but had a huge object which was already defined with braces and it wasn't working properly. Now eveything is fine. No problem. :)

Answer (score 12):

There is even more smooth way to do this:

```
this.init = function(){
  // method body
}();
```

This will both create method and call it.

Comment: Only works if you don't need to set properties in the method.  Otherwise Daniel Earwicker ^

Answer (score 3):

See below for one possible answer, and some corrections to your code.

```
function myClass(v1, v2) 
{
    // public vars
    this.var1 = v1;

    // private vars
    // use var to actually make this private
    var var2 = v2;

    // pub methods
    this.init = function() {
        // do some stuff        
    };

    // private methods
    // this will be private as though it had been declared with var
    function someMethod() {
        // do some private stuff
    };

    //call init
    this.init();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo when converting my real class to a simple example for the question.

Answer (score 3):

> JavaScript classes introduced in ECMAScript 2015 are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is not introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance.
>
> - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

When using this syntax, because only the `constructor()` method is run on instantiation you can't auto-instantiate an object. You always have to add `user = new MyUser()`

```js
var user;

class MyUser {
  constructor(var1, var2) {

    this.var1 = var1;
    this.var2 = var2;

  }

  static staticMethod() {

    // accessed directly with the class name `MyUser`

  }

  instanceMethod() {

    // accessed with object instance
return true
  }

}

user = new MyUser('hey','there')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
this.init();
```

to your myClass function.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```js
class MyClass {
this.v1 = "hello";

init = () => {
// do something
  }

constructor(){
  this.init()
  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).