# What is the use of the init() usage in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, init

What is the meaning and usage of the `init()` function in JavaScript?

Comment: init is just shorthand for initiate.  Typically it is used to create a "new Object()".   Like the init() function in jQuery returns a new jQuery object.

Comment: @LiamWilliam - initialize

Answer (score 142):

JavaScript doesn't have a built-in `init()` function, that is, it's not a part of the language. But it's not uncommon (in a lot of languages) for individual programmers to create their own `init()` function for initialisation stuff.

A particular `init()` function may be used to initialise the whole webpage, in which case it would probably be called from document.ready or onload processing, or it may be to initialise a particular type of object, or...well, you name it.

What any given `init()` does specifically is really up to whatever the person who wrote it needed it to do. Some types of code don't need any initialisation.

```
function init() {
  // initialisation stuff here
}

// elsewhere in code
init();
```

Comment: Is this still the case? I have some code now that does something like this: `var bEvent = function () {...}();` and afterward, `$(function () {
    // Launch functions
    bEvent.init()
  })`

Comment: @Jeff - Is what still the case? In your example, `bEvent` must refer to an object that has an `init() ` method, which you should see is created somewhere within the function body that you don't show.

Answer (score 38):

In JavaScript when you create any object through a constructor call like below

step 1 : create a function say Person..

```
function Person(name){
this.name=name;
}
person.prototype.print=function(){
console.log(this.name);
}
```

step 2 : create an instance for this function..

```
var obj=new Person('venkat')
```

//above line will instantiate this function(Person) and return a brand new object  called  Person {name:'venkat'}

if you don't want to instantiate this function and call at same time.we can also do like below..

```
var Person = {
  init: function(name){
    this.name=name;
  },
  print: function(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};
var obj=Object.create(Person);
obj.init('venkat');
obj.print();
```

in the above method **init** will help in instantiating the object properties. basically init is like a constructor call on your class.

Answer (score 2):

NB. Constructor function names should start with a capital letter to distinguish them from ordinary functions, e.g. `MyClass` instead of `myClass`.

Either you can call `init` from your constructor function:

```js
var myObj = new MyClass(2, true);

function MyClass(v1, v2) 
{
    // ...

    // pub methods
    this.init = function() {
        // do some stuff        
    };

    // ...

    this.init(); // <------------ added this
}
```

Or more simply you could just copy the body of the `init` function to the end of the constructor function. No need to actually have an `init` function at all if it's only called once.

Comment: And please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526916/javascript-class-call-method-when-object-initialized

Answer (score 0):

This is more like unreachable code

eg. if variable `x` or function `x()` is declared below the line where its
called this error generates:

```
 setPlayerOne();

let imageGenerator = (value) =>{
allImages = {
    1: 'images/dice1.png',
    2: 'images/dice2.png',
    3: 'images/dice3.png',
    4: 'images/dice4.png',
    5: 'images/dice5.png',
    6: 'images/dice6.png',
}
  return allImages[Number(value)];
}

findRandom = () =>{
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) +1
    return randomNumber;
}

let setPlayerOne = () =>{
   let img1 = document.querySelector('.img1').attributes.src;
   img1.value = imageGenerator(findRandom())
}

let setPlayerTwo = () =>{
    let img2 = document.querySelector('.img2').attributes.src;
    img2.value = imageGenerator(findRandom())
}

  
setPlayerTwo();
```

`setPlayerOne()` method will generate this but `setPlayerTwo()` will not generate;
this because `setPlayerOne()` was called before initialized by JS.