# How to call a method as soon as a class is initialized in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class

I have a class to create a user, when I add a init() function to the class which should be executed as soon as the class is initialized, it returns a SyntaxError.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526916/javascript-class-call-method-when-object-initialized) but get another SyntaxError

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, I want dob and age to be set on initialisation

```js
class User{
    constructor(name, dob){
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = null;
        this.age = null;
    }

    setAge(){
        let currentDate = new Date();
        let age = currentDate - this.dob;
        this.age = age;
    }

    setDob(dob){
        let dateArray = dob.split('/');
        let formatedDob = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1]-1, dateArray[0])
        this.dob = formatedDob
    }

    init(){
        setDob(dob);
        setAge();
    }

    this.init()
};

const user1 = new User('Garfield', '10/1/1999');
```

Comment: Do the assignment in `constructor` where you're currently assigning `null`…?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to the other answer, you can call any initialising methods directly in the constructor - that is what the constructor is there to do.

```
constructor(name, dob){
        this.name = name;
        this.setDob(dob);
        this.setAge();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, answer is in the constructor - so to simplify the code, take out the null in your code and re-write:

```
constructor(name, dob){
    this.name = name;
    this.setDob(dob);
    this.setAge();
}
```

Comment: Please don't add signatures to your posts, especially ones containing links back to your own content.  Stack Overflow is all about content—it's not a traditional discussion forum.  Feel free to add any information you'd normally have in your signature to your profile.  If people like your content, they might click through to find out more about you.

Comment: This answer was already given, only a few minutes before yours. Please delete it.